# how to handle configuration for accept and production environment in glassfish

Tags: glassfish

I want to create an application that is not aware of the environment it runs in.
The environment specific configuration I want to leave up to the configuration of glassfish.

So eg I have a persistence.xml which 'points' to a jta data source

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/DB_PRODUCTSUPPLIER</jta-data-source>
```

In glassfish this datasource is configured to 'point' to a connection pool.
This connection pool is configured to connect to a database.

I would like to have a mechanism such that I can define these resources for a production and an accept environment without having to change the jndi name. Because this would mean that my application is environment aware.

Do I need to create two domains for this? Or do I need two completely separate glassfish installations?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use clustering features (GF 2.1 default install is often developer mode, so you'll have to enable clustering, GF 3.1 clustering seems to be on by default).

As part of clustering, you can create stand alone instances that do not participate in a cluster.  Each instance can have its own config.  These instances share everything under the Resources section, and each instance can have separate values in the system properties, most importantly these are separate port numbers.

So a usage scenario would be that your accept/beta environment will run on it's own instance with different ports (defaults being 38080, 38181, etc., assuming you're doing an http app).  When running this way, your new instance will be running in a separate JVM.  With GF 2.1, you need to learn how to manage the node agent.  With GF 3.1, you won't have to worry about that.

When you deploy an application, you must choose the destination, called a Target, so you can have an accept/beta version on one instance, and a production version on the other instance.

This is how I run beta deployments with our current GF 2.1 non-clustered setup and it works pretty well.

Comment: You could also do it with different domains, but then you won't get the benefit of sharing the resources.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't help me a lot. My problem is that the resources are still shared (as you said). This means that e.g. my jdbc resource will still look at the same database. What I need is an instance that is using the same jndi name but with different values. It looks like this is not possible without creating a new domain.

Comment: Sorry I understood that backwards I guess.  What is an "accept" environment then?  Maybe like what I call "staging"?  We have 3 glassfish environments.  Dev, Staging, Beta/Production.  Dev and Staging are on separate servers and databases from Beta/Production.  We have built a custom installer/configurator to help reduce the grunt work for all the glassfish configuration.  It helps reduce mistakes too.

Comment: yes, we have something similar. So what I wanted to do is use one glassfish domain with maybe 2 local instances for the accept/staging and prod environment. But this didn't work as the jdbc resources are shared. So I need a separate domains or separate gf servers (as it would seem)